# I write this code with React and am not been navigated to the url. Pls can someone help out. How can I navigate to a given url in react

Tags: reactjs

I write this code with React and am not been navigated to the url. Pls can someone help out. How can I navigate to a given url in react.

```
doSubmit = () => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = this.state.data;
    const response = auth.login(username, password);
    if (response) {
      return <Navigate to={"/profile"} />;
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
    if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 400) {
      const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
      errors.username = ex.response.data;
      this.setState({ errors });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you using react-router? Which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: am using "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation), you can try `useNaviagte` hook to navigate to your required URL.